# Can anyone explain me what actually the value inside third brackets / [2] after str.split("|", expand=True) means?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

```
df1["state"] = df1["place_with_parent_names"].str.split("|",expand=True)[2]
```

what [2] actually indicate of a string split method.

Comment: now you can check again

Comment: Just print `df1["place_with_parent_names"].str.split("|",expand=True)`, and look at the dataframe. In particular the column names.

Answer (score 1):

A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would have been useful, but imagine that your code looks something like this (note I haven't included the `[2]` yet):

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["place_with_parent_names"], data = ['A|B|C','D_E_F','G|H|I'])
df_1["place_with_parent_names"].str.split("|",expand=True)
```

Running the code generates this result, so adding a `[2]` at the end simply slices to column 2 as shown:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the correct explanation, Thank you @DaveB

Answer (score -1):

the split function return a list so [2] is the index of the required string

Comment: You're forgetting that there is a dataframe involved: `str.split()` returns a new dataframe, and `[2]` is used on that new dataframe.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).